# Creating a list in PyMongo

Tags: python, pymongo

How does one create a list in **PyMongo**?

```
C = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost",27017)
db = C.coll.savee
Val= 12345
db.insert_one(["LIST",Val])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since mongo databases use key-value pairs to save data. Send a dictionary in insert_one parameter. That will solve your problem.

```
db.insert_one({"LIST":Val})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list (array):

```
db.insert_one({"LIST" : [Val]})
```